# Generating SNMP traps

Tags: networking, snmp, network-protocols

I am trying to implement just half of the SNMP functionality. On certain events, I want to create trap corresponding to each event. I am using C and Linux.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this? Do I need to use any open source utilities?Some of the events that I want to notify are very specific to my application. How to go about implementing this case?

I am new to SNMP. I have couple of basic questions: How agent and manager figure about what property i.e. object is being referred to? Do they both parse the MIB? How is MIB shared between agent and manager?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to execute Net-SNMP executable called snmptrap,

http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptrap.html

Of course, you can also link to its underlying library so as to call the C functions directly.

About your basic questions on SNMP, you should start from a book, such as Essential SNMP or Understanding SNMP MIBs.